# How do use python modules with pip?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip

Whenever I install a 3rd party package, say `python-docx`, using `pip` in the terminal, the package does not show up in PyCharm. Apparently, the corresponding package file should show up in the file named "site-packages" in PyCharm yet nothing shows up and when I run `import docx` in PyCharm(for the case of `python-docx`), it says the module could not be found.

I am using Python 3.9.6 with pip 21.2.1 on an M1 macbook air with PyCharm as my IDE and I am very new to coding so any help would be amazing because I have been so lost for a while now.

Comment: I'd recommend to try and narrow the problem down. When you run `python` or `python3` interactively from a terminal, can you `import` the modules? If so that would indicate the problem is with PyCharm (configuration), and not Python or pip.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have reduced the problem to pycharm itself. The module is definitely downloaded and seems to be recognised in my interactive session terminal but not in pycharm. Would you recommend I try to rectify the supposed configuration issue in pycharm or use a different IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a new project in PyCharm the default is that it creates a new virutal environment deriving from your base interpreter. This is very useful as in different projects that rely on different third party packages you don't install all of them globally. This means: whatever packages you pip-install to your global interpreter (after creation of a venv) will not show up in your venv.

When using PyCharm there are 2 ways to install packages to your venv.

1. Activate your venv in Terminal and then pip-install the packages you want. Command `source pathToYourProject/bin/activate`. Pip-install the packages you want in that env.
2. You can also use PyCharm to manage that. Go to: Settings > Project: "Your Project" > Python Interpreter. There you see all the packages installed to your interpreter. In the bottom left corner you find a "+" symbol. Click it, search for the third party package you want to install and install it.